# Get job status in Azure Runbook

Tags: powershell, azure, automation, runbook

I would like to have a runbook run on a schedule but exit if the last job hasn't finished running (i.e. if the schedule is every 2 hours and a job takes 2.5 hours then the next job shouldn't run).

I've tried to use Get-AzureAutomationJob to get the last job status (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/automation-runbook-execution/#retrieving-job-status-using-windows-powershell), but I can't get it to work. I presume all the preamble to get the subscription etc is required.

"Get-AzureAutomationJob : The Automation account was not found."

```
$ConnectionAssetName = "AzureClassicRunAsConnection"

# Get the connection
$connection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionAssetName        

# Authenticate to Azure with certificate
Write-Verbose "Get connection asset: $ConnectionAssetName" -Verbose
$Conn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $ConnectionAssetName
if ($Conn -eq $null)
{
    throw "Could not retrieve connection asset: $ConnectionAssetName. Assure            that this asset exists in the Automation account."
}

$CertificateAssetName = $Conn.CertificateAssetName
Write-Verbose "Getting the certificate: $CertificateAssetName" -Verbose
$AzureCert = Get-AutomationCertificate -Name $CertificateAssetName
if ($AzureCert -eq $null)
{
    throw "Could not retrieve certificate asset: $CertificateAssetName.       Assure that this asset exists in the Automation account."
}

Write-Verbose "Authenticating to Azure with certificate." -Verbose
Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $Conn.SubscriptionName -      SubscriptionId $Conn.SubscriptionID -Certificate $AzureCert 
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId $Conn.SubscriptionID

$job = (Get-AzureAutomationJob –AutomationAccountName "THE NAME OF THE AUTOMATION ACCOUNT AS IT APPEARS IN THE PORTAL" –Name "JobStatusTest" | sort LastModifiedDate –desc)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you would need to use Get-AzureRMAutomation job for that. Let me elaborate on that, I think in march 2016 Microsoft removed Azure Automation from the OLD azure model and now it is present only in the new one. so you would need to add RM to your commandlets

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that but i get the same error; "Get-AzureRmAutomationJob : The Automation account was not found"

Comment: well, then you just have to check the spelling, that might be the trick? also you would want to specify the -ResourceGroup switch and the resourcegroup switch